# C# error in read mp3 tags

Tags: c#, datagridview, mp3, id3

I'm writing a program which reads MP3 ID3v1 tags. My problem: in my `DataGridView` I get a tag value and unnecessary symbols "\0". Yet it doesn't write the genre!

Here my code:

```
  public class MusicID3Tag
        {

            public byte[] TAGID = new byte[3];      //  3
            public byte[] Title = new byte[30];     //  30
            public byte[] Artist = new byte[30];    //  30 
            public byte[] Album = new byte[30];     //  30 
            public byte[] Year = new byte[4];       //  4 
            public byte[] Comment = new byte[30];   //  30 
            public byte[] Genre = new byte[1];      //  1
        }

string[] fullfilesPath=Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,"*.mp3*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
int capacity = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.mp3*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
                        GlobalVariables.Var1 = capacity;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= capacity-1; i++)
                       {
                        string filePath = fullfilesPath[i];
                        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                        {
                            if (fs.Length >= 128)
                            {
                            MusicID3Tag tag = new MusicID3Tag();

                            fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
                            fs.Read(tag.TAGID, 0, tag.TAGID.Length);
                            fs.Read(tag.Title, 0, tag.Title.Length);
                            fs.Read(tag.Artist, 0, tag.Artist.Length);
                            fs.Read(tag.Album, 0, tag.Album.Length);
                            fs.Read(tag.Year, 0, tag.Year.Length);
                            fs.Read(tag.Comment, 0, tag.Comment.Length);
                            fs.Read(tag.Genre, 0, tag.Genre.Length);
                            string theTAGID = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.TAGID);

                            if (theTAGID.Equals("TAG"))
                            {

                                string Title = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Title);
                                string Artist = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Artist);
                                string Album = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Album);
                                string Year = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Year);
                                string Comment = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Comment);
                                string Genre = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Genre);
                                dt.Rows.Add(Artist, Title, Album, Year, Genre);
                                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I don't know much about MP3 tags, but "\0" is the escape sequence for a string termination.  If your genre is nothing but "\0", then it would stand to reason that the string being pulled is empty, meaning it contains no data or its being pulled incorrectly, yes?

Comment: string ReadAscii(this BinaryReader input)
{
    List<byte> strBytes = new List<byte>();
    int b;
    while ((b = input.ReadByte()) != 0x00)
        strBytes.Add((byte)b);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(strBytes.ToArray());
}

Comment: Also - Is there are reason you're writing your own? There are libraries that can do this for you? http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3dotnet/ or http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: "\0" added in all tags...I think if my tag artist weighs 10 bytes then other 20 bytes filled with "\0"! Libraries i can't use.

Comment: string ReadAscii(this BinaryReader input) { List<byte> strBytes = new List<byte>(); int b; while ((b = input.ReadByte()) != 0x00) strBytes.Add((byte)b); return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(strBytes.ToArray()); }<--- what this?